# PHP / SQL: Update Table C if meet condition after updated in Table A and Table B

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I got some issues with my current code. Example, on a PHP page, there's a table that displays all tools that borrowed the users. In that table, each data rows contain a checkbox. Users can select any tools that they want to return first by tick the checkbox and press "return" button.

At Server-side, after clicking the "return" button, it will go to the page named return_selected.php. At this page, it will update Table A and Table B. This one is successful.

Now, I want to update Table C if all there's a condition, for example, ALL tools returned. This one I still do but failed. Below is the code

return_selected.php

```
<?php

    include("../../../../config/configPDO.php");
    include("../../../../config/check.php");

    $tools_id = $_POST['tools_id'];
    $borrow_id = $_POST['borrow_id'];

    $checkbox=explode( ',', $_POST['ids'][0] );

    for($i=0;$i < count($checkbox); $i++){
        $tools_id=$checkbox[$i];

        $sql="UPDATE ets_tools SET borrow_id = NULL WHERE tools_id=:tools_id";
        $query=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':tools_id' => $tools_id));

        $sql2="UPDATE ets_tools_borrow SET time_to = GETDATE() WHERE tools_id=:tools_id";
        $query3=$conn->prepare($sql2);
        $query3->execute(array(':tools_id' => $tools_id));

        // want to update table if all tools returned.

        $query2 = "
           SELECT 
              ets_tools.tools_id, ets_tools.tools_name, ets_tools.borrow_id,
              ets_borrow.time_from, ets_borrow.time_to, ets_borrow.status_id
           FROM ets_tools 
           INNER JOIN ets_borrow ON ets_tools.borrow_id = ets_borrow.borrow_id
           WHERE ets_tools.borrow_id IS NOT NULL AND ets_borrow.borrow_id = :borrow_id
        ";

        $sql2=$conn->prepare($query2);
        $sql2->execute(array(':borrow_id' => $borrow_id));

        if($sql2->rowCount() > 0)
        {

            header("Location: return.php");

        }else{

            $sql3="UPDATE ets_borrow SET time_to  = GETDATE(), status_id = 2 WHERE borrow_id=:borrow_id";
            $query3=$conn->prepare($sql3);
            $query3->execute(array(':borrow_id' => $borrow_id));

            header("Location: return.php");

        }

    }

?>
```

Can anyone know how to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the following:

- As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php), `PDOStatement::rowCount()` *returns the number of rows affected by the last `DELETE`, `INSERT`, or `UPDATE` statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object* and for most databases the number of rows returned from a `SELECT` statement is not returned correctly. So, you may use a `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` approach to get this count.
- For your specific case you may try to use an `UPDATE ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ...`  statement to update the rows in the `ets_borrow` table and skip this `SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ...` statement.
- I'm not sure if I understand corectly the use of `header("Location: return.php");` in a `for` loop, probably you need to redirect after this loop.

Example, based on your code:

```
<?php

    include("../../../../config/configPDO.php");
    include("../../../../config/check.php");

    $tools_id = $_POST['tools_id'];
    $borrow_id = $_POST['borrow_id'];

    $checkbox=explode( ',', $_POST['ids'][0] );

    for($i=0; $i < count($checkbox); $i++) {
        $tools_id=$checkbox[$i];

        $sql = "UPDATE ets_tools SET borrow_id = NULL WHERE tools_id = :tools_id";
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':tools_id' => $tools_id));

        $sql2 = "UPDATE ets_tools_borrow SET time_to = GETDATE() WHERE tools_id = :tools_id";
        $query2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);
        $query2->execute(array(':tools_id' => $tools_id));

        $sql3 = "
            UPDATE ets_borrow 
            SET time_to = GETDATE(), status_id = 2 
            WHERE 
                (borrow_id = :borrow_id1) AND
                NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM ets_tools 
                    INNER JOIN ets_borrow ON ets_tools.borrow_id = ets_borrow.borrow_id
                    WHERE ets_tools.borrow_id IS NOT NULL AND ets_borrow.borrow_id = :borrow_id2
                )
            ";
        $borrow_id1 = $borrow_id;
        $borrow_id2 = $borrow_id;
        $query3 = $conn->prepare($sql3);
        $query3->execute(array(':borrow_id1' => $borrow_id1, ':borrow_id2' => $borrow_id2));
    }
    
    header("Location: return.php");
    
?>
```